# Replace or remove numbers next to text in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: windows-8, sublime-text-2

I have list of keywords with numbers next to them in Sublime Text 2.

Something like

```
 Sample tag 141870
 Sample tag 36786
 Sample tag 10651
 Sample tag 266357
 Sample tag 2251
```

Would there be any simple and quick efficient method to removing just the numbers next to the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your Middle Mouse Button, press and hold it at the end of the first line. Move the mouse down so that it will create multiple cursors, one at the end of each line.

[image]

Hold `CTRL` + `SHIFT` and then use the left arrow key to highlight the numbers.

[image]

Hit the delete key, and then click off anywhere to get rid of the multiple cursors.

[image]

I have used this kind of technique for thousands of rows of data. Cool thing is that you can also simultaneously type as well on multiple rows. You also can use `CTRL` + `Left Mouse Click` to place a new cursor at a specified location.

Comment: Awesome works perfectly. One other thing is that the tags have a few blank spaces and I would like to backspace them so they match/align properly. Would there be a way of doing that? Here's a screenshot: http://i.imm.io/1iahk.png

Comment: if you want everything left-aligned, use Ctrl-A to select all, then hit Ctrl-[ a couple of times to de-indent stuff.

Comment: shift + tab will also de-indent

Answer (score 2):

1. `ctrl` + `H`
2. enable regex (click the button next to Aa at the left side)
3. at find write `\d+`
4. click replace all

The image below explains everything:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@kobaltz's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/657779/137557) is good, but I'd just like to add a slightly easier method of placing the multiple cursors. Instead of using the mouse to place all of them, first select the text `Sample tag`. Then, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> to "Quick Find All", which will select all occurrences of the phrase. You can then hit your <kbd>→</kbd> right arrow key to remove the selection but keep all the cursors. **Then**, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to select to the end of the line and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>, or you can straightaway hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>, which is the shortcut to delete to the end of the line from the current position.

Comment: I suggested this method because sample tag may not be the actual text in his document, but good info as well.

Comment: good point, I didn't think of that